# Wordpress permalinks reach apache 404 not wordpress 404.php or their real respective pages. Redirects or apache config mistake?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost

I just did clean wordpress install and set up its .htaccess like they say i should do :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

when i try to go to some address in my browser like `http://localhost:888/blog/` i get 404 error from server. I dont even get directed by wordpress to wordpess's own 404 page.

When i look up my site's error log:

```
[Sat Apr 20 10:43:36 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/alan/projects/pin_wp/blog, referer: http://localhost:888/
```

So this leads me into thinking that i have messed up my virtualhost conf somewhere - since im one big noob in that area:

```
alan@alan:~/projects/pin_wp$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/localhost-pinwp 
Listen 888
<VirtualHost *:888>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/alan/projects/pin_wp
    ServerName html

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/alan/projects/pin_wp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-pinwp.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-pinwp.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Could someone please help me fix this issue and point me out what kind of dumb mistakes i've done this time.

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i figured it out with little help.

I changed apache conf from:

```
<Directory /home/alan/projects/pin_wp>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /home/alan/projects/pin_wp>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
</Directory>
```

And everything works now.

Alan